How to fix malformed entry in sources file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources

Malformed entry 1 in sources file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.


File contents;
Types: deb
URIs: cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.10 Kinetic Kudu - Release amd64 (20221020)]/
Suites: kinetic
Components: main restricted

I'm running Noble 24.04

Does this answer your question? How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?

A quick look at my own file shows the following, I'm using Ubuntu plucky (25.04) so the initial install media will provide me nothing useful (just as 22.10 media would in the question), but that source will still be a problem unless I find the install media which I don't have any more.
In my case, I've just disabled the source.  You'll note it's done by adding a
Enabled: no

to the file.
guiverc@d7050-next:~$   cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources 
Enabled: no
Types: deb
URIs: cdrom:[Xubuntu 23.10 _Mantic Minotaur_ - Daily amd64 (20230829)]/
Suites: mantic
Components: main restricted universe multiverse

This can be achieved with a text editor, OR GUI tool too (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for help).

Answer provided (really so I can tag this question as dup for a new question)
